# Using looking-at in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to replace some text starting with a dot and ending with a dot or an equal sign. For example `a.test=3`. I would like to replace this with `a['test']=` (conversion from Matlab to Python).

I tested the `looking-at` function in Emacs Lisp:

```
(defun test-la ()
  (interactive)
  (when (looking-at "\\.\\(.*?)\\)[=.]")
    (message "ok")))
```

But when the point is on a dot, it is not showing `"ok"`..

Comment: Did you mean to put the question mark after the parenthesis?  I.e. `(looking-at "\\.\\(.*)?\\)[=.]")`

Comment: @legoscia No, I tried to use the non greedy variant of the star operator, see: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html

Comment: Right, then the parenthesis is probably superfluous, as it would match `a.test)=3`, and the expression you're looking for is `(looking-at "\\.\\(.*?\\)[=.]")`

Comment: @legoscia Thanks! I just realized that mistake myself.. I must have got confused by all the parenthesis :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an extra parenthesis in your regexp.  The one you currently have would match `a.test)=3`.  Try this instead:

```
(looking-at "\\.\\(.*?\\)[=.]")
```

Answer (score 4):

I never use it myself, but lots of people find `re-builder` useful for writing regexps.  Another option is to use `rx`, which uses a Lisp-ish syntax which is less succint but also less cryptic.